# Android TextView stays null

Tags: java, android

I keep getting a nullpointer when trying to setText() on menuText.

my onCreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView menuText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.personals);
```

activity_main:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:itemIconTint="#4c3327"
        app:itemTextColor="#c75b12"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

header:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/personals"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This was working without issues, the exception is thrown by:

```
menuText.setText("text goes here");
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

I have to mention that is was working fine, I changed:
`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0` from 22 to 25 and added
`com.karumi:dexter:3.0.2`, did the permissions and now getting this issue.

No matter what I do the menuText stays null, even tried injecting with butterknife.

```
@InjectView(R.id.personals)
    TextView menuText;
```

Still does not work. any suggestions?

Comment: Where do you call `setText`?

Comment: findViewById(R.id.personals) may be returning null.

Comment: make sure textview with id "personals" is included in activity_main

Comment: TextView Declared in which layout activity_main or anyother layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To successfuly look for widget in Navigation Drawer's header, you need to get the correct container view first by calling `getHeaderView()` on it:

```
View header = ((NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view)).getHeaderView(0);
```

and then having `header` pointing to the right ViewGroup can call `findViewById()` on it for your target widget as usual:

```
TextView iv = ((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.personals));
```

Also, what you use `@InjectView` for if you are searching yourself?

Comment: Thank you, this helped and was useful, I still need to understand why is was working before the changes I made.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);        
 View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
 TextView username = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.personals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

menuText = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id. personals);
menuText.setText("text goes here");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerView = vNavigation.getHeaderView(0);
TextView text = headerView.findViewById(R.id.personals);
text.setText("It is working now");
```

Try it it will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
View head = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView username = (TextView) head.findViewById(R.id.personals);
```

This Should Work.

Answer (score 0):

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

TextView tv= (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id. personals);
tv.setText("text goes here");
```